# Determining possible values of a complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I'm looking at the complex integral:

$ \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{C(0;r)}\frac{cos(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz  $

and I'm wondering how I'd go about determining all the possible values of this  for $ r>0 $ and $ n \geq 0$

With no similar examples at my disposal I'm wondering how I might approach this.

I'm thinking about using the fact that the integral of $\frac{1}{z}$ is $2 \pi i$

Answer (score 1):

By Cauchy's integral formula for higher derivatives we have $$\frac{2\pi i}{n!}f^{(n)}(0)=\int_{C(0;r)} \frac{\cos(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz$$ where $f(z)=\cos(z)$ and $f^{(n)}(0)$ is the $n$th derivative of $f$ at $0$.

Comment: I'm not so familiar with the Cauchy Integral Theorem. Could you elaborate on how you got this equality?

Answer (score 0):

This is the residue of 
$$
f(z) = \frac{\cos(z)}{z^{n+1}}
$$
at $0$ see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_%28complex_analysis%29). Since $f$ is analytic in $\mathbb{C}^*=\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ it doesn't depend on $r>0$. To compute this value note that for 
$$
  f(z) = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} a_n z^n
$$
the residue at $0$ is $a_{-1}$, which is shown using what you mentioned and the fact that this same integral over $\frac{1}{z^n}$ for any $n\not=1$ is zero. Hence to obtain your answer figure out what the series expansion of $f$ is.